# Why I need to stringify an array of objects, and parse after retrieve it, in React/Redux?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to go, but it's working. I'm not sure either of this is a problem of React/Redux, or just javascript behaviour.

This is my REDUX Actions:

```
export const getDetectedPersonList = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {  
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/detectedPersonsListWS")
          .then(function(response) {
            if (response.status >= 400) {
              throw new Error("Bad response from server");
            }
              return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(detections) { 

              var detected = [{"a":1},{"b":2},{"c":3},{"d":4}];

                dispatch({
                  type : GET_DETECTED_PERSON_LIST,
                  payload : JSON.stringify(detected)
                })
             })     
        }
    }
```

And in REACT's presentational component I have:

```
 componentDidMount() {
  this.props.getDetectedPersonList();
 }  

 render() {
    if (typeof this.props.detectedPersonListJson == 'string'){
      console.log(this.props.detectedPersonListJson);
      var json = JSON.parse(this.props.detectedPersonListJson);
      console.log(json); //The array is perfect as created before (detected)
    }
```

The detected array is obviously mock (in real world I expect a REST response), but ilustrates the question I think, it's not a problem of async action.
My biggest problem is that I'm validating props, before and I was expecting an array, but cannot send the array directly because I receive: [object object] and is interpreted as string by typeof, but it's not... And I get an error doing JSON.parse(detected), if I haven't done JSON.stringify(detected) before.

Makes any sense? Best practices to follow? Thanks so much.

Comment: You don't, so there's likely something else going on, like in the reducer, which you don't include. Obviously right now it'll be a string because you stringify it.

Comment: But without stringifyint it was interpreted as an string by javascript's typeof function, as I said in the question.

Comment: Again: then there's something else going on. *With* `stringify` it's *guaranteed* to be "interpreted as a string". If you're getting a hardcoded object "interpreted as a string" then you need to include your reducer that's doing something with the action payload: if you send an object and it's being mapped to something else then something else is happening. There's absolutely nothing "automatic" in React and Redux that magically transforms payloads into strings.